# como actualizar el valor de una variable dentro de una funcion en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

basicamente estoy haciendo un formulario donde se puedan hacer retiros, depositos y consultar saldo, sin embargo no se como actualizar los valores dentro de una funcion, me explico al ejecutar la funcion depositar (que es parte de un onclick de un boton) la funcion se ejecuta y me muestra el nuevo saldo, sin embargo para ir a la funcion retirar o consultar saldo, me ejecuta de nuevo el saldo anterior sin ser actualizado por el deposito y si lo pongo fuera d ela funcion me dice que no está definido.
PD: tambien debo poner un contador de cuantas veces se ha depositado y retirado.
PD2: es una tarea de la u basica, asi que nada de frameworks ni nada extra, debe ser con lo basico de javascript, cualquier ayuda les agradezco mucho

```
function captura(){
let nombre= document.getElementById("nombre").value;
let identidad= document.getElementById("identidad").value;
let telefono= document.getElementById("telefono").value;
let email= document.getElementById("email").value;

console.log(nombre,identidad,email,telefono);


    
}

let miCuenta = new Cuenta;
function datos(){ 
    let nroCuenta= document.getElementById("numerodecuenta").value;
    let clave = document.getElementById("clave").value;

    
    if (nroCuenta==123 && clave == 1018120) {

        console.log(miCuenta.consultarSaldo(depositar(nuevoSaldo)));
            
     
  } else {

    console.log('Numero de cuenta o clave incorrecta');
    
  }
}


function depositar() {
  let nroCuenta= document.getElementById("numerodecuenta").value;
  let clave = document.getElementById("clave").value;

  
  if (nroCuenta==123 && clave == 1018120) {

    valorDeposito = document.getElementById("valordeposito").value;
    miCuenta.depositar(valorDeposito);
    console.log(miCuenta.consultarSaldo());
    nuevoSaldo= miCuenta.depositar(valorDeposito);
    miCuenta.consultarSaldo= nuevoSaldo;
      
          
   
} else {

  console.log('Numero de cuenta o clave incorrecta');
  
}
  
    
}

function retirar() {
    let valorRetiro = document.getElementById("valorretiro").value;
    miCuenta.depositar(valorRetiro);
    console.log(miCuenta.consultarSaldo());


}
```

y esta es la clase cuenta

```
class Cuenta
//propiedades de la clase cuenta
{
    #nroCuenta;
    #idcliente;
    #saldo;
    #telefono;
    #email

    saldo = this.#saldo;
    constructor ()
    {
        this.#nroCuenta = "123";
        this.#idcliente = "1018120";
        this.#saldo = 0,0; 
        this.#email= "";
        this.#telefono="3151456879";
    }

    depositar( valorDeposito )
    {
        this.#saldo=this.#saldo + valorDeposito;

        return;
    }
    consultarSaldo()
    {
        return this.#saldo;
    }
    retirar( valorRetiro )
    {
        let respuesta;
        if (this.#saldo >= valorRetiro)
        {
        this.#saldo = this.#saldo - valorRetiro;
        respuesta = true;
        }
        else
        {
         respuesta = false;   
        }
        return respuesta; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hice un codepen con vanilla JS, dale un vistazo e intenta comprender las operaciones, use localstorage para guardar los datos en el navegador y asi pudieras hacer pruebas, aplique un poco de bootstrap pero igual lo puedes remover, y el resto y los mas importante esta en JS pues revisarlo es una operacion de suma y una operacion de resta, y un valor zero que ira tomando la suma o resta de las operaciones, le agregue un login simulando la cuenta de usuario, completamente editable, si bien me entretuve un rato suerte, saludos https://codepen.io/jonath4n/pen/eYMvaWN?editors=1010

Comment: Si lo pegas en tu proyecto y lo pruebas en local y modificas el local storage se puede mantener aun cuando se simula el cierre de sesion, solo que codepen lo refresca por eso se borra, has tu pruebas